# Failed assertion: line 168 pos 15: 'icon != null': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, searchbar

I am creating a searchbar in flutter and while doing this I found the above error. It is showing `icon != null`. I can not understand why is it showing! Can anybody tell me how do I solve this. It is showing the below error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Consumer<PatientDataNotifier>(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<PatientDataNotifier>]):
'package:flutter/src/material/icon_button.dart': Failed assertion: line 168 pos 15: 'icon != null': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Consumer<PatientDataNotifier> file:///F:/ShortedCubeSolutionProjects/flutter_data_table/lib/homescreen.dart:124:16
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      new IconButton (package:flutter/src/material/icon_button.dart:168:15)
#3      HomeScreen.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_data_table/homescreen.dart:130:21)
#4      Consumer.buildWithChild (package:provider/src/consumer.dart:177:19)
#5      SingleChildStatelessWidget.build (package:nested/nested.dart:260:41)
#6      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4701:28)
```

Below is my code.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  String appBarTitle = 'Patient Details';
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();

  var icon;
  
  Widget bodyData(PatientDataNotifier patientDataNotifier, BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black),
        ),
        child: DataTable(
        //..........
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(80),
        child: Consumer<PatientDataNotifier>(
          builder: (context,  patientDataNotifier, _){
            return AppBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              title: Text(appBarTitle),
              actions: [
                new IconButton(
                    icon: icon,
                    onPressed: (){
                      if(this.icon == Icons.search){
                        this.icon = new Icon(
                          Icons.close,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        );
                        this.appBarTitle = new TextFormField(
                          controller: nameController,
                          style: new TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white
                          ),
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color:  Colors.white),
                            hintText: 'Search..',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color:  Colors.white),
                          ),
                          onChanged: (text){
                            patientDataNotifier.getPatients(text);
                          },
                        ) as String;
                      }
                    }
                )
              ],
            );
          },

        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Consumer<PatientDataNotifier>(
          builder: (context, patientDataNotifier, _){
            return bodyData(patientDataNotifier, context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please help me to do this! I am stuck!

Comment: where is your variable assignment for icon variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that you are having is that your icon is null and you cannot pass a null value to the child in the iconButton. You are using a stateless widget, but you should use a statefull because you want to reload the view when you change the value. I have changed a bit the logic so it will show one widget or another widget in your app when you are using the search bar.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();

  bool textField;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.textField = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(80),
        child: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: textField ? new TextFormField(
            controller: nameController,
            style: new TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white
            ),
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color:  Colors.white),
              hintText: 'Search..',
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color:  Colors.white),
            ),
            onChanged: (text){
            },
          ) : Text('Patient Details'),
          actions: [
            new IconButton(
                icon: textField ? new Icon(
                  Icons.close,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ) : Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: (){
                  setState(() {
                    this.textField = !this.textField;
                  });
                }
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you are creating a search bar I would recommend you to use the search delegate.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! but here I am using `Consumer`, so is it necessary to use a `StatefulWidget` instead of a `StatelessWidget`?

Comment: You can use consumer in a StatefulWidget and in a StatelessWidget. The consumer is to control the change of your provider only. You will not be able to change your app bar to a search bar if you are not using a StatefulWidget or you should use another provider to control that change. You can add the rest of the code that I have taken out because I tested it in my machine before I sent it to you.

Comment: You welcome. With the code that I commented you will be able to change between the AppBar and the Search bar with the Icons also changing.

Comment: You welcome. I recommend you to use types in your variables it will make your life much easier :)

Answer (score 0):

You create a `var` called `icon` but you didn't assign a value to it.

Try adding a valid value to the `icon` parameter to your `IconButton`.

```
IconButton(
icon: Icon(Icons.search)
...
),
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you never give your icon a value. Start by giving your icon an initial value:

```
var icon = Icon(Icons.camera, color: Colors.white);
```

Secondly, in the `onPressed` function you assign a new value to the variable icon but the UI will never show this change, because you didn't call `setState`. You also check if your Icon eg `new Icon(...)` object is equal to an Icon eg `Icons.camera`, which will always return false hence they're not the same type of object.

So change this part of your onPressed function:

```
if (this.icon == Icons.search) {
  this.icon = new Icon(
    Icons.close,
    color: Colors.white,
  );
}
```

to this:

```
if (icon.icon == Icons.search) {
  setState(() {
    icon = new Icon(
      Icons.close,
      color: Colors.white,
    );
  });
}
```